# How to keep the </a> closing tag on same line and all the others in new line in a Vue.js project?

Tags: html, vue.js, eslint, prettier

`vue/html-closing-bracket-newline` adds an unexpected space after the link text. removing the space creates a conflict and error in prettier and eslint. looking for a solution to over come this with a simple config change instead of a line by line ignore comment.

`vue/html-closing-bracket-newline` moves all the closing tags to new line, which adds an unexpected space after the link text

```html
<a
 href="#"
 place="linkText"
 target="_blank">
lorum ipsum
</a>
```

[link space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duGik.png)

---

expected code syntax format is

```html
<a
 href="#"
 place="linkText"
 target="_blank">lorum ipsum</a>
```

But it creates a conflict between prettier / eslint / vue.

[prettier / eslint error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrmsA.png)

An easy solution would be adding `<!-- eslint-disable-line -->` in each anchor tag. But we are looking for a simple solution to cover all anchor tags in the project.

Comment: Do you need to use a plugin to make your code pretty?  Usually you would just use vue loader and template compiler as you're not bothered what your code looks like after it's compiled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the whitespace-sensitive formatting.
This attribute `htmlWhitespaceSensitivity` accept the following options:

- `"css"` - Respect the default value of CSS display property. For Handlebars treated same as strict. "Default"
- `"strict"` - Whitespace (or the lack of it) around all tags is considered significant.
- `"ignore"` - Whitespace (or the lack of it) around all tags is considered insignificant.

You can fix it by adding the following rule to your `.eslintrc.js` file (rules section):

```js
"prettier/prettier": [
  "warn",
  {
    htmlWhitespaceSensitivity: "strict"
  }
]
```

It would consider the whitespace "significant" for all cases. That means:

```html
<!-- input -->
<span class="dolorum atque aspernatur">Est molestiae sunt facilis qui rem.</span>
<div class="voluptatem architecto at">Architecto rerum architecto incidunt sint.</div>
<div class="voluptatem architecto at">
  Architecto rerum architecto incidunt sint.</div>
<div class="voluptatem architecto at">
  Architecto rerum architecto incidunt sint.
</div>

<!-- output -->
<span class="dolorum atque aspernatur"
  >Est molestiae sunt facilis qui rem.</span
>
<div class="voluptatem architecto at"
  >Architecto rerum architecto incidunt sint.</div
>
<div class="voluptatem architecto at">
  Architecto rerum architecto incidunt sint.</div
>
<div class="voluptatem architecto at">
  Architecto rerum architecto incidunt sint.
</div> <!-- in this case you would have the whitespace -->
```

It looks ugly as it puts the `</div` at the end of the string and `>` the next line. But it solves the problem.

You can read more about it here: 
https://prettier.io/blog/2018/11/07/1.15.0.html#whitespace-sensitive-formatting
And here is an old Github issue on prettier stating the same as you mentioned here: 
https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/6290

Answer (score 1):

- Use `Ctrl` + `,` on Windows (or `CMD` + `,` on Mac) to open your editors settings.
- Search for **HTML closing bracket**, and you will be presented with a screen that looks like the image attached. [image: image attached]

If it is *unchecked*, you can go ahead and check it.
What this setting does is add the closing bracket on the same line as the last letter as opposed to dropping it to the next line where it sits alone, as you are currently experiencing.

You can also edit it in your `settings.json` file like the below:

```
"prettier.bracketSameLine": true
```

---

If you want to have access to even more `brackets` setting options. You can search for **bracket** in your VS code user setting and play around with the options.

Comment: that would be IDE / editor specific and will fail while build the code in other environment.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
  <a href="#"
     place="linkText"
     target="_blank">
    lorum ipsum</a>
```

Comment: but it throws an prettier / eslint error.